# Automated content creation for the web?

Tags: automation, seo

I see a lot of new websites lately which create automated content, most notable SiteGuruji and 7zoom:

http://www.siteguruji.com/site/youtube.com

Is there an application framework or text analysis framework available to create such sites? SiteGuruji is doing full SEO analysis of the sites as well. Is there an SEO analysis library available? How do I do such an analysis?

Sorry for the noobish question, but i am new to programming and thus I am not sure which direction to start in.

Answer (score 0):

By SEO did you mean this section of the page?

http://www.siteguruji.com/site/youtube.com#seo_status ?

I don't think any frameworks are available for SEO... however you can check out NLTK for text analysis and natural language processing:

http://www.nltk.org/book

Comment: but what about automation of tasks? i mean how i can do such large mining?

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to write your own classes to scrape content from the site and third party sites and analyse it. I have not found something ready for this. Bits fom here and there, you can use.

Personally, I have created everything from scratch using zend framework as basis.